# pandas AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt' when using apply on groupby

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following `df`,

```
code    date1        date2
2000    2018-03-21   2018-04-04
2000    2018-03-22   2018-04-05
2000    2018-03-23   2018-04-06
```

When I tried

```
df_code_grp_by = df.groupby(['code'])

df_code_grp_by.apply(lambda x: x.date2 - x.date1).dt.days.sum(level=0).reset_index(name='date_diff_sum')
```

I got

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'dt'
```

`date1` and `date2` are both `dtype('<M8[ns]')`, I am wondering how to fix it.

I am using `Pandas 0.22.0`, `Python 3.5.2` and `Numpy 1.15.4`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better here is create index by `code` column and subtract `Series`:

```
df = df.set_index('code')
df = (df.date2 - df.date1).dt.days.sum(level=0).reset_index(name='date_diff_sum')
print (df)
   code  date_diff_sum
0  2000             42
```

Problem of code is `apply` return rows (maybe bug):

```
df_code_grp_by = df.groupby(['code'])

df = df_code_grp_by.apply(lambda x: x.date2 - x.date1)
print (df)
                     0                 1                 2
code                                                      
2000  1209600000000000  1209600000000000  1209600000000000
```

Possible solution is use `np.sum`:

```
df = (df_code_grp_by.apply(lambda x: np.sum(x.date2 - x.date1))
                    .dt.days
                    .reset_index(name='date_diff_sum'))
print (df)
   code  date_diff_sum
0  2000             42
```

Comment: thx for your reply, can you tell me what's wrong with my code

Comment: @daiyue - Investigating.